# PHPMailer mails getting rejected by exim after upgrade to WHM/cPanel 11.30

Tags: php, phpmailer, exim, smtp-auth

After updating to WHM/cPanel 11.30.0, PHPMailer mails are now being rejected by exim. This is my code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Password = '****';
$mail->Host = "mail.***.com";
$mail->Username = '***@***.com';
$mail->From = "***@***.com";
$mail->FromName = '***@***.com';            
$mail->AddAddress($recipient);  
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
$result = $mail->Send();
```

PHPMailer is returning with no errors but in the exim reject log it says

> H=(localhost.localdomain) [a.n.i.p] F=<...@....com> rejected RCPT <...@....com>: (localhost.localdomain) [a.n.i.p] is currently not permitted to relay through this server. Perhaps you have not logged into the pop/imap server in the last 30 minutes or do not have SMTP Authentication turned on in your email client.

Can anyone help?

Comment: swiftmailer seems to work so im abandoning phpmailer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really common, convoluted error message from exim, but the short of it is that the server isn't set up to accept email from the recipient domain.

It possible that the update has cleared out any IP's defined in your relayhosts. Make sure the host your sending from is added to the /etc/exim_smtp_whitelist, and that this is being used in your cpanel configuration.

WHM > Exim Configuration Editor > Advanced Editor

accept hosts = /etc/exim_smtp_whitelist